# Which is a better way to know the type of a variable in Java Script

Tags: javascript

If I have a variable var a, and I want to check if it is of type array I can either do

```
a.constructor === Array
```

or,

```
a instanceof Array
```

which is a better way and why ?

Comment: typeof a can be used but I was wondering how these two comparisons work

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) function:

```
Array.isArray(a);
```

Comment: I am not looking for other methods I am just curious that what is the difference between these two and is there any drawbacks of one of them ?

Comment: Well, StackOverflow is a question and answer site. When you ask for "how do I know if something is an array", then people will answer that. For your more specific question, also check the linked duplicate about `instanceof` vs `constructor`.

Comment: @AvinashSharma Yes, the drawback is that while `Array.isArray()` *always* tells you if something is an array, both `a.constructor === Array` and `a instanceof Array` will fail in some cases ([see this for details](http://web.mit.edu/jwalden/www/isArray.html)).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof a === 'object' && Array.isArray(a)) {
    //its array
}
```

UPDATE : the difference

```
var a = Object.create(Array.prototype);

alert(a instanceof Array);                       //TRUE
alert(a.constructor === Array);                  //TRUE  
if (typeof a === 'object' && Array.isArray(a)) { //FALSE 
    alert(true);
} 
else {
    alert(false);
}
```

**but then you do**

```
var a = new Array();  // or var a = [];  etc

alert(a instanceof Array);                       //TRUE
alert(a.constructor === Array);                  //TRUE  
if (typeof a === 'object' && Array.isArray(a)) { //TRUE 
    alert(true);
} 
else {
    alert(false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To return variable type of a use below

```
typeof(a)
```

Comment: `typeof` does not do what the question asks for.

Comment: I have given choice for getting data type of variable in javascript, if you go through heading question answer is correct.